# cannot post aMutipart/form-data using an HttpRequest in APEX

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout

I am trying to call an endpoint in APEX which requires Authorization and the body which it expects is multi/form-part. I am getting evertytime access denied. I have tried using postman and the endpoint is fine. below is my code.

```
 public void APICALL()
   {

     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     String endPointURL = 'https://abcwerr.ffff.com/v2/ttttt';
    String userName = 'BlahBlah';
    String password = 'BlahBlah';
   Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName + ':' + password);
    String authorizationHeader = 'Basic' +
    EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
     req.setEndpoint(endPointURL);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    req.setHeader('Authorization',authorizationHeader);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    string bdy = 'merchant_url='+ AppForm.Business_Website__c;

    req.setbody(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bdy)); 
    Http http = new Http();

    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    this.SpiderResponse = res.getBody(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`multipart/form-data` requires a boundary between the parts, even if there is just one part.

See [Steps required to support POSTing multipart/form-data Content-Type from Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html)

You also need a space between the 'Basic' and encoded value in the header. E.g.

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```